# Possible JFrog CLI bug: "jf rt upload ----target-props=" doesn't remove properties

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

The following sets the `repo/test` properties to `name2=value2` as I expected

```
jf rt upload repo/test --target-props=name1=value1
jf rt upload repo/test --target-props=name2=value2
```

However, I've found that

```
jf rt upload repo/test --target-props=name1=value1
jf rt upload repo/test --target-props=
```

leaves `repo/test` properties as `name1=value1`.  I expected the second upload to remove all properties from `repo/test`.  I also tried

```
jf rt upload repo/test --target-props=name1=value1
jf rt upload repo/test
```

and got the same results.  Is this a bug or working as expected?  If is this working as expected, how can I delete all properties when uploading an artifact?

Comment: @yahavi Do you know?